# How could I recreate this particular synth sound?

Tags: composition, synthesizer, electronic-music, synthesis

I was wondering if anyone has any ideas about recreating a synth sound, or at least getting something relatively similar:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kswhzrr0ywoijfj/synthexport-28082015.mp3?dl=0

I've exhausted a lot of presets trying to get that breathy / blown sound but without much luck.

Thanks.

Comment: post it to somewhere public, at least, youtube, soundcloud etc

Comment: I haven't clicked the dubious DropBox link but to get breath/wind noises you want to get a noise generator/noise wave shape going.

Comment: With this type of question I refer people to an excellent little book called " Walsh's Synthesizer Cookbook" does an excellent job of explaining how to synthesize sounds from scratch.

Comment: To the person that voted to close this, these kind of questions are acceptable.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: May I invite you to a personal chat - http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27548/room-for-mramosch-and-todd-wilcox

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with any cheap Soundmodule or Soundcard. Just go to the wind section of the GM module select a Panflute sound, put a low-cut filter on it to filter out the low end and EQ the high end to make it more aggressive. A compressor will give the sound an additional kick.

If you are lucky your sound module does have a bottleblow sound as variation of the flute sounds. This will already have the low end filtered out but the same procedure as above could give you an even better result. To fatten the sound a bit of chorus, harmonizer or flanger would do the trick...

Finally you have to play the right notes - a single note while sound-editing might fool you...